# Proving $\mathbb{Z}_{(m,n)}$ is a submodule of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ and for every $[a]_{n}$ we get $[a]_{n}m=[0]$ where $(m,n)=\gcd(m,n)$ .

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, modules

Proving $\mathbb{Z}_{(m,n)}$ is a submodule of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ and  every $[a] \in \mathbb{Z}_{(m,n)}$ can be regarded as an element $[a]_{n}$ such that  $[a]_{n}m=[0]$ where $(m,n)=\gcd(m,n)$ .

First and foremost I need to convince myself that $\mathbb{Z}_{(m,n)} \subset\mathbb{Z}_{n}$. That is, for every $[a] \in \mathbb{Z}_{(m,n)} $, then $[a] \in \mathbb{Z}_{n}$. So I picked and element from the class $[a] \in \mathbb{Z}_{(m,n)} $, $x \in [a]_{(m,n)}$, and I would like to show that $x \in [a]_{n}$. Since $x \in [a]_{(m,n)}$, then $x \cong a (mod (m,n))$, this means $(m,n) | x-a$ so there is $k \in  \mathbb{Z}$ such that $(m,n)k=(x-a)$. In order to prove $x \in [a]_{n}$ I need to show $n \mid x-a$. But since $(m,n) \mid n$ we got $(m,n)k'=n$ for some $k' \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore I need to show $(m,n) k' \mid (m,n) k$. But I can't figure out how I show that.

Now let's go to prove that $\mathbb{Z}_{(m,n)}$ is a submodule of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$. Then I need to show that for every $[a] \in \mathbb{Z}_{(m,n)}$ and every  $r \in \mathbb{Z}$ we got $[a] r = [ar] \in \mathbb{Z}_{(m,n)}$ and $[a] + [b] =[a +b] \in \mathbb{Z}_{(m,n)} $ for every $[a], [b] \in \mathbb{Z}_{(m,n)} $. My attempts to prove this statement we more messy and less fruitfuil that the contention $\mathbb{Z}_{(m,n)} \subset\mathbb{Z}_{n}$. Not to mention how I got stucked proving $[a]m=[0]$ for every $[a] \in \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ originally contained in $\mathbb{Z}_{(m,n)}$.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{Z}_{(m,n)}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ (yes, that technically means it's not a submodule).  Instead, you should show that there is a submodule $M$ of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ which is isomorphic [as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules] to $\mathbb{Z}_{(m,n)}$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Any hint about how to find this isomophic copy of $Z_{n}$ contained in $Z_{(m,n)}$ ?

Comment: It's the other way around (an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Z}_{(m,n)}$ contained in $\mathbb{Z}_n$).  The best way is likely to be $$M = (0 :_{\mathbb{Z}_n} (m)) := \{x \in \mathbb{Z}_n \mid mx = 0\}$$